# HTML title attribute not shown in shadow dom elements

Tags: javascript, html, attributes, web-component, native-web-component

I created my own HTML Element with web components. It adds a button to its shadow root. But the title of the button is not drawn when hovering over it, although the title attribute is set on the html element. I am using Windows 10 and Firefox version 58.0.2. Any ideas?

```js
class Test extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();

    var shadow = this.attachShadow({
      mode: 'open'
    });
    var button = document.createElement('input');
    button.type = 'button';
    button.value = 'Test button';
    button.title = 'Title of my button';

    shadow.appendChild(button);
  }
}


customElements.define('te-test', Test);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/webcomponentsjs/1.1.0/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
<te-test></te-test>
```

Comment: Title attribute and title tooltip are showing on Firefox 58 on Mac for me.

Comment: actually now it works with @BrettDeWoody correction (i.e. polyfill added)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this behaviour is intended but when I change

```
button.title = 'Title of my button';
```

to

```
this.title = 'Title of my button';
```

it works. But as already mentioned by you it seems that the first way works with other OSs and browser. So it will be probably fixed by Mozilla in future releases.

Comment: bug's still there in v59

Answer (score 0):

I see the title in Chrome 64.0.3282.186 on Mac:

[image: Title Hover]